# C++ Specify variable type a posteriori in derived class

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I have two databases of different types of objects with some common functions so I thought to create a parent class with the definitions of the common functions. The idea is that these functions have to do the same operations even though the type of objects is different. A silly example:

```
class Database
{
public:
    // retrieve size of the dataset
    int Size() const {return list_.size();}
};

class DerivedDatabase : public Database
{
private:
    // list of dataset objects
    std::vector<Object1> list_;
};

class DerivedDatabase2: public Database
{
private:
    // list of dataset objects
    std::vector<Object2> list_;
};
```

One solution is to define the function as `virtual Size() const =0` and then have the derived classes override it. However the idea is to have it already implemented for when I have to create new types of DataBases. Is there a way to specify a posteriori the variable type in the derived classes? The two derived databases are inherently different and they behave completely differently except for some functions, which are common. Thus they have to be separate objects

Comment: [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) may help.

Answer (score 2):

You may use [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) to factorize code, something like:

```
template <typename T> class Database
{
// T should have a container named list_
public:
    // retrieve size of the dataset
    int Size() const { return AsDerived().list_.size(); }
private:
    const T& AsDerived() const { return static_cast<const T&>(*this); }
    T& AsDerived() { return static_cast<T&>(*this); }
};
```

And then

```
class DerivedDatabase : public Database<DerivedDatabase>
{
    friend class Database<DerivedDatabase>;
private:
    std::vector<Object1> list_;
};

class DerivedDatabase2 : public Database<DerivedDatabase2>
{
    friend class Database<DerivedDatabase2>;
private:
    std::vector<Object2> list_;
};
```

Note that `DerivedDatabase` and `DerivedDatabase2` doesn't share a common base type here

[Live example](https://ideone.com/DYJ0Wo)

Answer (score 1):

Sure, that what `template`s are for:

```
class Database {
    virtual int size() = 0;
public:
    // retrieve size of the dataset
    int Size() const {return size();}
}

template<typename T>
class DerivedDatabase: public Database {
    std::vector<T> list_;
    int size() const {return list_.size();}
}
```

Comment: With that, `Size` cannot have the given implementation in `Database`.

Comment: The two derived databases are inherently different and they behave completely differently except for some functions, which are common. In the solution you purpose the size function is defined in the derived class. Is it possible that the function is specified in the base class but run with different variable types for each of the child classes?

Comment: @iprafols no reason why you couldn't simply work through the `virtual int size()` interface in your derived classes that have (non-templated) `std::vector`s of different types.